# Liferay error: The TagExtraInfo class for "portlet:renderURL" (com.liferay.taglib.portlet.RenderURLTei) could not be instantiated

Tags: liferay, portlet, taglib, liferay-7

I'm attempting to create a very simple portlet using Liferay 7.3.4 by following these instructions:

- https://help.liferay.com/hc/en-us/articles/360017871312-Writing-the-My-Greeting-Portlet

I've cut out everything but the following code, but still cannot define a portlet:renderUrl tag.

[image]

The error message I am receiving is as follows:

```
The TagExtraInfo class for "portlet:renderURL" (com.liferay.taglib.portlet.RenderURLTei) could not be instantiated
```

I am using Maven to build this project, with the following pom.xml for the portlet defined above:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <artifactId>partner-portal-modules</artifactId>
        <groupId>partner.portal</groupId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.xyz.portal.organization</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.xyz.portal.organization</artifactId>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.liferay</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.liferay.asset.taglib</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.liferay</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.liferay.comment.taglib</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.liferay</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.liferay.frontend.taglib</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.liferay</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.liferay.frontend.taglib.dynamic.section</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.liferay</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.liferay.frontend.taglib.form.navigator</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.liferay</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.liferay.frontend.taglib.util</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.liferay</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.liferay.journal.taglib</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.liferay</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.liferay.layout.taglib</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.liferay</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.liferay.site.taglib</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.liferay.portal</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.liferay.portal.kernel</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.liferay.portal</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.liferay.util.taglib</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.portlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>portlet-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.osgi.service.component.annotations</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>biz.aQute.bnd</groupId>
                <artifactId>bnd-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>4.3.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>bnd-process</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>biz.aQute.bnd</groupId>
                        <artifactId>biz.aQute.bndlib</artifactId>
                        <version>4.3.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.liferay</groupId>
                        <artifactId>com.liferay.ant.bnd</artifactId>
                        <version>3.2.3</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.liferay</groupId>
                <artifactId>com.liferay.css.builder</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <baseDir>src/main/resources/META-INF/resources</baseDir>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifestFile>${project.build.outputDirectory}/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</manifestFile>
                    </archive>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/META-INF/resources/**/.sass-cache/</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

My Liferay project is targeted for 7.3.4, with the following pom:

- https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/liferay/portal/release.portal.bom.compile.only/7.3.4/release.portal.bom.compile.only-7.3.4.pom

This pom includes the following version for javax.portlet:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.portlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>portlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Yet the taglib in my auto-generated view.jsp is as follows:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet"%>
```

That is, Maven says Java Portlet v3.0, and taglib says portlet v2.0.  Not sure if this is the issue, my research thus far has not yet resulted in a proper solution.

Curious if others have seen this same issue, and how it was resolved.

Thanks,
Randy

Comment: Have you tried if this is an issue at runtime? The JSP editor sometimes can't properly resolve everything, while the runtime environment can.

Comment: I've found the following, seems like this is indeed an issue with the JSP editor:
https://liferay.dev/forums/-/message_boards/message/112285636